# How to Activate or deactivate workflow, Trigger, Validation rule and flow through apex class?

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, validation-rule

Is it possible to activate or deactivate workflow,trigger,validation rule and flow through apex class ? If yes then how to achieve this..

Comment: No, not from Apex. As you stated, only through Metadata API, then deploy this changes.

Comment: deactivate for the life of the transaction or permanently?

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the better ways is to use custom setting or any checkbox to bypass validation and workflow rules etc.
You can check or uncheck the checbox from apex code.

```
ex: AND(
NOT(ByPass_VR__C),
...
```

Comment: More info on how to do this can be found here: http://www.absi.be/personalize-automation-salesforce.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response but i want to do this through metadata api or any direct apex class without using Custom setting or custom label.